# Is there a way to have my macbook set its brightness based on it running from battery or from line power?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power-management, auto-brightness

Basically I'd like to have one brightness setting configured for when I'm plugged in through the adapter and charging the macbook from wall power, vs a lower brightness setting when I'm running off battery to preserve battery life. This configuration swap would be in response to the changed power state of the laptop. Does MacOS support such behavior?

Comment: There is the setting in the Battery tab of System Preferences' Energy Saver pane, although it doesn't dim that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While macOS does not support the exact behavior you are looking for (setting custom brightness when switching between power states), you can configure your Mac portable to slightly dim the brightness automatically when on battery power.

To do that, go to System Preferences → Energy Saver and enable **Slightly dim the display while on battery power**.

[image]

Comment: That works and it's beautiful, but my mac won't restore full brightness when I plug it in with the adapter. 
That's very annoying, how can I implement this basic functionality?

Comment: @Salomanuel What version of macOS are you running? Can you check under Display preference pane if you have Automatically adjust brightness enabled?

Comment: I'm running the current Monterey 12.4. Neither setting of "Automatically adjust brightness" manages to restore the brightness to the maximum, after I plug the power adapter back in.

Comment: I'm not the only one though:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431159/monterey-is-there-a-macos-preference-to-automatically-revert-back-the-brightne