# Monterey - Is there a macOS preference to automatically revert back the brightness level when the MacBook is plugged in?

Tags: display, battery, charging, power, auto-brightness

As the title is self-descriptive, I'm looking for a macOS preference to automatically revert back the brightness level when the MacBook is plugged in as the preference `"Slightly dim the display while on battery power"` is checked for me that automatically dims the display brightness while on battery power.

p.s. I'm using the latest stable version of macOS, `macOS Monterey 12.0.1`.

Comment: That preference should also restore the brightness to its original level when connecting to mains power. (I can't find a direct quote from Apple, but note that the preference dims ‘_while_ on battery power’, nor just ‘when starting to use battery power’.) If your display isn't doing that, maybe there's some other reason (e.g. it's set to automatically adjust brightness)?

Comment: Many thanks for your comment, much appreciated. Yes, I've checked that preference ("Automatically adjust brightness") but it is unset as well. @gidds